# How to send a dictionary through params webapp2 python?

Tags: python, alamofire, webapp2

I have a dictionary in Swift like so:

`let params : [String : Any] =`

`["user_key": "ag1kZXZ-Z29hbC1yaXNlchELEgRVc2VyGICAgICAgIAKDA", 
 "post_text": "Lol", 
 "trip": ["posted_by": "", 
         "endAddress": "", 
         "post_text": "Lol", 
         "startAddress": ["state": "IL", 
                          "city": "Oak Park", 
                          "address1": "6503 West North Avenue", 
                          "address2": "", "zipCode": ""], 
         "time": "", 
         "role": "", 
         "eta": ""]]`

When I send this in the params object of Alamofire, the webapp2 accesses the params by `self.request.get('user_key')` and so forth, however, it does not get the 'trip' parameter. ```self.request.get('trip') returns nothing.

How do I send this dictionary to webapp2 Request Handler?

Comment: Maybe you can use a tool such as Wireshark to see the network traffic of your server, that could help you see if the trip parameter is actually transmitted.

Comment: Simply using ```print(self.request.params)``` will print what was passed into the request handler. Thank you though

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To access the trip dictionary you would need to use:

`class CreateMediaPostTaskHandler(webapp2.RequestHandler):
    def post(self):
        params = self.request.params
        start_address_city = params['trip[startAddress][city]']`